# How to access my Notebook after setting BIOS passwordto blank?

Tags: bios, passwords, password-protection, anti-theft

I recently bought an IdeaPad U410. A few days later I set a User Password and an Admin Password in my BIOS.
Until today I did not go back into BIOS. But since it started to bother me to always type two passwords (BIOS + Win8), I wanted to remove the first one.
When I entered BIOS, I could strangely only modify the User Password. There was no way to access any other option but the system time. I found that quite strange, so I tried to change my User password, because I thought, that I would maybe get access to the other options then. 
Well, that was not the case. So, I thought, that I could at least get rid of this password now, and entered nothing as a password.
Problem now is, that when I rebooted my Notebook, it still asked me for a password. And it neither takes my "new" empty password, nor my old one, nor the Admin BIOS password

I really need this notebook to run! There are project data on it, that I need for my thesis

Can you help me with that?

**Edit:**
Is there a way to enter a non-breaking space without a numblock? Maybe this will do the job?! I don't know...

Comment: If you want to access your data quickly, remove HDD from the laptop and connect it to another PC. You should be able to access your files.

Comment: The notebook has anti-theft protection, so I guess it is encrypted

Answer (score 1):

One way to reset your password in to remove the CMOS battery for a few minutes and then put it back again.

Don't do this unless you know exactly how to do this with your laptop. Doing this yourself might also void the warranty.

If your laptop is still covered under warranty, it would be better to have an authorized technician do this for you.

Comment: problem is that I need the notebook _and_ the data on it tomorrow..

Comment: If it is urgent, go to a local computer service shop and get it fixed. Again, this might void the warranty.